# Iphone system log - recurring springboard warning

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, springboard

I used the Iphone configuration utility to help a developer troubleshoot an unrelated issue.  I noticed that console was being hammared with the same two warnings every few seconds.  I don't notice any performance issues, but it's making it impossible to debug anything else.
My phone is jailbroken, running IOS: 4.3.3

Any ideas on what could be causing this?  Here is a sample of the console output that repeats:

```
Jun 28 15:35:41 Tylers-iPhone SpringBoard[4405] <Warning>: ITEM: 5
Jun 28 15:35:41 Tylers-iPhone SpringBoard[4405] <Warning>: ITEM: 20
Jun 28 15:35:46 Tylers-iPhone SpringBoard[4405] <Warning>: ITEM: 5
Jun 28 15:35:46 Tylers-iPhone SpringBoard[4405] <Warning>: ITEM: 20
Jun 28 15:35:51 Tylers-iPhone SpringBoard[4405] <Warning>: ITEM: 5
Jun 28 15:35:51 Tylers-iPhone SpringBoard[4405] <Warning>: ITEM: 20
Jun 28 15:35:56 Tylers-iPhone SpringBoard[4405] <Warning>: ITEM: 5
Jun 28 15:35:56 Tylers-iPhone SpringBoard[4405] <Warning>: ITEM: 20
Jun 28 15:36:01 Tylers-iPhone SpringBoard[4405] <Warning>: ITEM: 5
Jun 28 15:36:01 Tylers-iPhone SpringBoard[4405] <Warning>: ITEM: 20
Jun 28 15:36:06 Tylers-iPhone SpringBoard[4405] <Warning>: ITEM: 5
Jun 28 15:36:06 Tylers-iPhone SpringBoard[4405] <Warning>: ITEM: 20
Jun 28 15:36:06 Tylers-iPhone SpringBoard[4405] <Warning>: ITEM: 6
Jun 28 15:36:06 Tylers-iPhone SpringBoard[4405] <Warning>: ITEM: 7
Jun 28 15:36:11 Tylers-iPhone SpringBoard[4405] <Warning>: ITEM: 5
Jun 28 15:36:11 Tylers-iPhone SpringBoard[4405] <Warning>: ITEM: 20
Jun 28 15:36:16 Tylers-iPhone SpringBoard[4405] <Warning>: ITEM: 5
Jun 28 15:36:16 Tylers-iPhone SpringBoard[4405] <Warning>: ITEM: 20
Jun 28 15:36:21 Tylers-iPhone SpringBoard[4405] <Warning>: ITEM: 5
Jun 28 15:36:21 Tylers-iPhone SpringBoard[4405] <Warning>: ITEM: 20
Jun 28 15:36:26 Tylers-iPhone SpringBoard[4405] <Warning>: ITEM: 5
Jun 28 15:36:26 Tylers-iPhone SpringBoard[4405] <Warning>: ITEM: 20
Jun 28 15:36:27 Tylers-iPhone SpringBoard[4405] <Warning>: ITEM: 6
Jun 28 15:36:27 Tylers-iPhone SpringBoard[4405] <Warning>: ITEM: 7
Jun 28 15:36:31 Tylers-iPhone SpringBoard[4405] <Warning>: ITEM: 5
Jun 28 15:36:31 Tylers-iPhone SpringBoard[4405] <Warning>: ITEM: 20
```

There's so much of that I won't paste it all in, but here are some of the other messages that might help:

```
Jun 28 15:08:06 Tylers-iPhone com.apple.SpringBoard[4257] <Notice>: Jun 28 15:08:06 Tylers-iPhone SpringBoard[4257] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0


Jun 28 15:12:50 Tylers-iPhone com.apple.SpringBoard[4366] <Notice>: MS:Warning: nil class argument
```

And I'm not sure if this is related, but it the only time i found similiar springboard warnings in the log:

```
Jun 28 15:12:58 Tylers-iPhone SpringBoard[4366] <Warning>: CleanStatus OS: 4.3.3
Jun 28 15:12:58 Tylers-iPhone SpringBoard[4366] <Warning>: Boo. I'm loading CleanStatus now
Jun 28 15:12:58 Tylers-iPhone SpringBoard[4366] <Warning>: ITEM: 0
Jun 28 15:12:58 Tylers-iPhone SpringBoard[4366] <Warning>: ITEM: 1
Jun 28 15:12:58 Tylers-iPhone SpringBoard[4366] <Warning>: ITEM: 2
Jun 28 15:12:58 Tylers-iPhone SpringBoard[4366] <Warning>: ITEM: 3
Jun 28 15:12:58 Tylers-iPhone SpringBoard[4366] <Warning>: ITEM: 4
Jun 28 15:12:58 Tylers-iPhone SpringBoard[4366] <Warning>: ITEM: 5
Jun 28 15:12:58 Tylers-iPhone SpringBoard[4366] <Warning>: ITEM: 6
Jun 28 15:12:58 Tylers-iPhone SpringBoard[4366] <Warning>: ITEM: 7
Jun 28 15:12:58 Tylers-iPhone SpringBoard[4366] <Warning>: ITEM: 8
Jun 28 15:12:58 Tylers-iPhone SpringBoard[4366] <Warning>: ITEM: 9
Jun 28 15:12:58 Tylers-iPhone SpringBoard[4366] <Warning>: ITEM: 10
Jun 28 15:12:58 Tylers-iPhone SpringBoard[4366] <Warning>: BTM: attaching to BTServer
Jun 28 15:12:58 Tylers-iPhone SpringBoard[4366] <Warning>: ITEM: 11
Jun 28 15:12:58 Tylers-iPhone SpringBoard[4366] <Warning>: ITEM: 12
Jun 28 15:12:58 Tylers-iPhone SpringBoard[4366] <Warning>: ITEM: 13
Jun 28 15:12:58 Tylers-iPhone SpringBoard[4366] <Warning>: ITEM: 14
Jun 28 15:12:58 Tylers-iPhone SpringBoard[4366] <Warning>: ITEM: 15
Jun 28 15:12:58 Tylers-iPhone SpringBoard[4366] <Warning>: ITEM: 16
Jun 28 15:12:58 Tylers-iPhone SpringBoard[4366] <Warning>: ITEM: 17
Jun 28 15:12:58 Tylers-iPhone SpringBoard[4366] <Warning>: ITEM: 18
Jun 28 15:12:58 Tylers-iPhone SpringBoard[4366] <Warning>: ITEM: 19
Jun 28 15:12:58 Tylers-iPhone SpringBoard[4366] <Warning>: ITEM: 20
Jun 28 15:12:58 Tylers-iPhone SpringBoard[4366] <Warning>: ITEM: 21
Jun 28 15:12:59 Tylers-iPhone SpringBoard[4366] <Warning>: LI: Debug Logging: 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Jailbroken iOS devices can easily run into troubles like this. iOS is a closed platform to maintain security and stability and this is pretty solid evidence of the opposite.

Pro-Apple preach aside, the log message overload is caused by an instability in Springboard, caused by this plugin for jailbroken iOS devices:

http://www.iphonedownloadblog.com/2011/01/29/cleanstatus-sanitizes-your-iphones-status-bar/

This isn't really a programing question, so next time, post it to [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: FYI, [su] doesn't consider smartphones computers, so smartphone questions are off-topic there. [apple.se] accepts user questions about all Apple hardware, including jailbroken iPhones.